# What are the steps for the LQ decomposition of a tall matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, matrix-decomposition, programming

I need to write an R function that decomposes a rectangular $6 \times 4$ matrix into $6\times 4$ lower triangular L matrix and an orthogonal Q matrix, however I can't seem to find any information on the steps I need to apply.  What I found is a work around, i.e apply a QR decomposition on the transpose of A, but in this case A will become a `fat` and I believe QR works for tall matrices. The function I try to mimic is the  [lq()](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/tensr/html/lq.html) function from the [tensr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tensr/index.html) package in R, but this function uses some C++ functions that are `hidden` and I need them to not be like that. Thanks in advance.